# prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, npm, installation-path, npm-version

I have installed NODEJS succesfully. But when I check for the versions, node version is showing correctly.But when I check for npm version,I get the following error along with the version.

```
'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program 
Files\nodejs\\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
 prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
5.3.0
```

I am unable to understand what went wrong during the installation.

Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you try to run `npm -g -v` and receive this error. This is normal behavior on Windows OS. You should have error on `npm -g install yo` or `npm -g ls`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the system configuration in System- Follow this configuration this is work for me

[image: System-Edit Enviroment variables- ComSpec C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe]